# I need to periodically reload an image with HTMX

Tags: htmx

I'm writing something akin to a status page that has an image on it. Periodically, this image should be refreshed.

I got it working by having a div-tag that refreshes an img-tag, but this is ugly as the image isn't loaded until after the swap, causing the page to blink during the reload.

I have the following markup:

```
        <div hx-trigger="every 5s" hx-get="/htmx/screenshotwrapper" hx-swap="innerHTML">
            <img class="htmx-indicator" src="/spinner.svg" width="640" height="480">
        </div>
```

So here I'll serve up a new img-tag from /htmx/screenshotwrapper which will in turn load the image. As it blinks it isn't really usable.

Comment: can you inline the image instead of loading it externally? (especially if it's an svg)

Comment: This was my idea as well, however, the inlined image is an attribute of the img-tag, so you can't target it with HTMX. If inlined images where <img>base64:...</img> however, we'd likely be able to target it.

Comment: I got this working by changing the file name with every refresh (added the current timestamp to the file name). Also disabled browser request caching as a new image (QR code in my case) is generated on every refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw; I gave up on HTMX and solved it with some pretty basic Javascript. It seems that HTMX and JS go rather well together. I've added the following script to the page:

```js
        function reloadImage() {
            var img = document.getElementById('dynamicImage');
            var currentSrc = "/htmx/screenshot"
            // Add a cache-busting parameter
            if (currentSrc.indexOf('?') > -1) {
                currentSrc = currentSrc.substring(0, currentSrc.indexOf('?'));
            }
            var newSrc = currentSrc + "?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime();
            // Preload the image
            var preloadedImg = new Image();
            preloadedImg.src = newSrc;

            preloadedImg.onload = function() {
                // Once the image is preloaded, replace the displayed image
                img.src = newSrc;
            };
        }

        setInterval(reloadImage, 5000);
```

and in the HTML I just did:

```html
<img id="dynamicImage" src="/spinner.svg" width="640" height="480">
```